# Round Sympy Mul with Units

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to round the output of a solve evaluation that has units attached to it.

For example:

```
solve(Eq(x, 22/7 * seconds), x)[0]
```

Outputs:

```
3.14285714285714*s
```

Is there a way to round it to `3.14*s` while keeping the `s`?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need this? It feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy expressions have the `.evalf()` method to approximate numbers. It accepts an optional parameter `n`, which specifies the number of digits the approximate expression will contain.

Supposing you expression is contained in the `expr` variable:

```
In [5]: expr
Out[5]: 3.14285714285714⋅s

In [6]: expr.evalf(n=10)
Out[6]: 3.142857143⋅s

In [7]: expr.evalf(n=2)
Out[7]: 3.1⋅s

In [8]: expr.evalf(n=3)
Out[8]: 3.14⋅s
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.